# Styling the text in a text area, prior to the first <br>

Tags: javascript, css

How can I style the 1st line of a text area up to the first line break?

Using ::first-line could work, when viewed on a mobile device the last word/words which flow over to the 2nd line won't be accounted for.

```
<p>
The first line of my paragraph.<br>
Another line.<br>
And another line.<br>
And yet another line.<br>
</p>
```

I was hoping to find a solution here, but no luck.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KQgu5/)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain javascript to wrap text before first `br` in `span`.

```js
var address = document.getElementById('address');
var content = address.innerHTML.split('<br>');
content[0] = '<span class="red">' + content[0] + '</span>';

address.innerHTML = content.join('<br>');
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="address">
  Joe Dirt<br>
  PO Box 842<br>
  New York NY 10012<br>
  800-555-5555<br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Update: For multiple elements you can use `querySelectorAll` and then loop each element and add `span`.

```js
var address = document.querySelectorAll('.address');

[...address].forEach(function(e) {
  var content = e.innerHTML.split('<br>');
  content[0] = '<span class="red">' + content[0] + '</span>';
  e.innerHTML = content.join('<br>');
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="address">
  Joe Dirt<br> PO Box 842<br> New York NY 10012<br> 800-555-5555<br><br>
</div>

<div class="address">
  Joe Dirt<br> PO Box 842<br> New York NY 10012<br> 800-555-5555<br><br>
</div>

<div class="address">
  Joe Dirt<br> PO Box 842<br> New York NY 10012<br> 800-555-5555<br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nenad, thank you, it is working, but my fault; i didn't mention it is a post type. So I need every 1st element red like this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thissideupmedia/oymmto09/

Comment: @user1664798 You can't have multiple same ids on page so use class instead, then you can write js like this https://jsfiddle.net/oymmto09/5/

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for the first line then. 
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkqb2xu1/)
Html would be this :

```
<span class="first-line">Joe Dirt</span><br>
```

and some fancy css stuff here :

```
.first-line {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but unfortunately I can not edit the HTML to add a class.

Comment: Then you should use the pure JS solution made by @linkinted - it's not modifying the html files even though it's modify the final html.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a JS approach, here is one

```js
$(function(){
  $('p').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html(); /* get the text */
    splText = text.split('<br>'); /* split it on the line breaks */
    splText[0] = '<span class="firstLine">'+splText[0]+'</span>'; /* add a span to the first line */
    text =  splText.join('<br>'); /* put it back togehter */
    $(this).html( text ); /* put it back in the element */
  });
});
```

```css
span.firstLine {
  color: red;
}
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
The first line of my paragraph.<br>
Another line.<br>
And another line.<br>
And yet another line.<br>
</p>
<p>
The first line of my paragraph.<br>
Another line.<br>
And another line.<br>
And yet another line.<br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for this. I altered your JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KQgu5/17/

First, I remove the first line of your div using:

```
var $line = $("#address").html().split("<br>")[0];
$("#address").first().contents().first().remove();
```

Second, I add the line back with a span around it:

```
$( "#address" ).prepend("<span class='first-line'>" + $line + "</span>");
```

Finally, all you have to do is style the first line in your CSS like:

```
.first-line {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, you solution also work, BUT how do I get the 1st line of every div to style? See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thissideupmedia/KQgu5/18/ Thank you.

Comment: @user1664798 Make sure each div has the same class, not id (an id has to be unique). After that, add an `each()` function to the JS. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KQgu5/19/

Answer (score 1):

If you want it dynamically try like this

```js
var elem = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML.split("<br>");
elem[0] = "<span class='myclass'>"+elem[0]+"</span>";
document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = elem.join("<br>");
```

```css
.myclass{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p>
The first line of my paragraph.<br>
Another line.<br>
And another line.<br>
And yet another line.<br>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi @user2486 , thank you, this is working, the only thing is I need to make the 1st line of every paragraph blue. See this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/thissideupmedia/fdexery6/ Thank you!